# How to create one method for different collections data types?

Tags: java, android

What I have:

```
Type dogType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Dog>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<Dog> dogList = context.deserialize(jsonObject.get("dog"), dogType);
HashMap dogMap=new HashMap();
for (int i=0; i<dogList.size(); i++) {
    Dog item = dogList.get(i);
    dogMap.put(item.getId(), item);
}
home.setDogs(dogMap);
```

What I would like to get:

```
home.setDogs(getMap(jsonObject, "dog", Dog.class));

private HashMap<???> getMap(JSONObject jsonObject, String name, ??? type) {
    ArrayList<???> list = context.deserialize(jsonObject.get(name), new TypeToken<ArrayList<type>>() {}.getType());
    HashMap map=new HashMap();
    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        ??? item = list.get(i);
        map.put(item.getId(), item);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Is it possible? What I need to set instead of "???"?

Comment: If your classes extends some parent class or implement some interface (e. g. Animal), use wildcard: `List<? extends Animal>`. Otherwise use `List<Object>` or just no-typed `List`, but it is not recommended.

Comment: By the way, returning concrete implementations on methods is also not recommended since it breaks "program over interface, not implementation" rule.

Comment: We need some more details about `Dog` class hierarchy. Where is `getId()` defined?And also, what is `context`? What is `home`? What type does `setDogs()` method accept?